# Orchard Placement, Move LogIn links

Tags: themes, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

VERY NEW TO ORCHARD, having a hard time wrapping my head around a couple of things but i am getting there.

I expected that the log in links would be a widget, they are not.
so what i am looking to do is move that to the top right of the page.

I have take the default theme and cloned it to my own so i can start a custom theme. I think i should be using the Placement.info to accomplish what i am trying to do. the hardship i am having there is

1. a comprehensive list of attributes to the placement
2. how to determin the Parts_[Name] of something <- i think this is the rule i need to set up to get the log in into the header. I have tried a handful of variations of this.

   ```
   <Place Parts_User="/Header:1"/>
   ```

any push in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check in the Layout.cshtml file, you will see a line of code somewhere near the top:

```
WorkContext.Layout.Footer.Add(New.User(), "10"); // Login and dashboard links
```

User is a shape, not a part. You can take a look at it in Orchard.Core/Shapes/Views/User.cshtml. To edit this view, make a copy of it and place it in your theme.

And the tool you will need for theme development is called Shape Tracing. It is part of the Developer Tools module, available in the gallery. This will let you inspect shapes and look at their attributes.